# VB 2010 - Button that opens DEFAULT email program and populates entries from txtboxes

Tags: vb.net, email

I've created a form in VB that requests some entries and through those entries a body for an email is created. Now I have to make a button that opens the default email client of the computer and populates the Body with the text that is generated through the form (I don't want it to send the email since the user is supposed to add the From and the Subject). I've managed to make it happen through this simple line :

```
Dim Text As String = Textbox1.Text
Process.Start("mailto:email@email.com?subject=Hello&body=" & Text)
```

However, when the email client opens the format of the body is messed up. There are supposed to be paragraphs and spaces but there aren't any. Can you help me fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

In order for MailTo to work properly, you need to URL Encode your message. The following should work:

```
Dim Text As String = Textbox1.Text
Process.Start("mailto:email@email.com?subject=Hello&body=" & System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Text))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dan. I had to change the framework so I could add the System.Web Reference in order for HttpUtility to work. The format is a lot better but still wherever there are supposed to be spaces between text there's the symbol "+" instead. For Example, instead of "Hello Peter. What's up?" it says "Hello+Peter.+What's+up?". Can you help me again ?

Comment: I googled it a bit and I found out that instead of "System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncoder" I should use "System.Uri.EscapeDataString". Dan thank you again for your time and help.